# Leer Varias Hojas de Excel en un Listview

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2010

estoy tratando de leer un archivo de excel que tiene varias hojas 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Necesito leer varias columnas de lo que hay en esas hojas por ejemplo del rango a1:a20 y c1:c20

El resultado listarlo en un listview, estoy intentando con varias sugerencias que aparece en el foro, pero solo me permite leer una hoja y necesito leer varias a la vez. De todas maneras les coloco el codigo que estoy usando.

Gracias de antemano

```
Public Class Frm_ImportarLibro
    Public Function Obtenerdatos(ByVal ruta As String, ByVal hoja As String, ByVal rango As String) As DataTable


        Dim cadenaConexion As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO';" &
                                       "Data Source=" & ruta


        Using cnn As New OleDbConnection(cadenaConexion)


            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}${1}]", hoja, rango)
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dtTemp As New DataTable("Prueba")
            da.Fill(dtTemp)
            Dim dt As DataTable = dtTemp.Clone()
            Dim rows As DataRow() = dtTemp.Select()

            For index As Integer = 0 To rows.Count - 1
                Dim row As DataRow = rows(index)
                If (row.Item(0) Is DBNull.Value) Then
                    Exit For
                End If

                dt.ImportRow(row)
            Next

            Return dt

        End Using

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías modificar el código de la siguiente manera:

```
    Public Function Obtenerdatos(ByVal ruta As String, ByVal hojasRangos As String) As DataTable


    Dim cadenaConexion As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO';" &
                                   "Data Source=" & ruta

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cnn As New OleDbConnection(cadenaConexion)


        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()
        Dim vhojas() As String = Split(hojasRangos, ";")
        Dim nTotalCols As Int32 = 0
        For Each hoja As String In vhojas
            ' Obtener el nombre de la hoja: '
            Dim nomHoja As String = Split(hoja, "$")(0)
            ' Obtener uno o más rangos de la hoja en curso: '
            Dim rango() As String = Split(Split(hoja, "$")(1), ",")
            For iCol As Int32 = 0 To rango.Length - 1
                If iCol + nTotalCols >= dt.Columns.Count Then
                    dt.Columns.Add(nomHoja + "$" + rango(iCol).Chars(0))
                    nTotalCols += 1
                End If
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}${1}]", nomHoja, rango(iCol))
                Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dtTemp As New DataTable("Prueba")
                da.Fill(dtTemp)
                Dim rows As DataRow() = dtTemp.Select()
                For index As Integer = 0 To rows.Count - 1
                    Dim row As DataRow = rows(index)
                    If Not (row.Item(0) Is DBNull.Value) Then
                        If index >= dt.Rows.Count Then
                            Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
                            dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
                        End If
                        dt.Rows(index).Item(nTotalCols - 1) = row.Item(0)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next


        Return dt

    End Using

End Function
```

Luego, para llamar a Obtenerdatos() separa las columnas con una coma (,) y las hojas con un punto y coma (;), así:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim hoja1Rangos As String = "hoja1$D15:D28,H15:H28"
        Dim hoja2Rangos As String = "hoja2$B8:B18"
        Dim dt As DataTable = Obtenerdatos(ruta, hoja1Rangos + ";" + hoja2Rangos)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]